# An efficient way of replacing list of keys with dict values?

Tags: python

Say I have a list of keys belonging in a dictionary:

```
dict = {"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4], "c":[5,6]}
keys = ["a","b","c"]
```

What's the most efficient way to replace all the keys in the list with the values in the dictionary?

ie,

```
keys = ["a","b","c"]
```

becomes

```
keys = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables `dict`, as it overshadows the builtin.

Comment: Can you not just get the values with dict.values()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` makes it easy:

```
map(d.get, keys)
```

(Or, in Python 3.x, `list(map(d.get, keys))`)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like so:

```
>>> # Please don't name a dictionary dict -- it overrides the built-in
>>> dct = {"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4], "c":[5,6]}
>>> keys = ["a","b","c"]
>>> id(keys)
28590032
>>> keys[:] = [dct[k] for k in keys]
>>> keys
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> id(keys)
28590032
>>>
```

`[:]` is only needed if you want the list object to remain the same.  Otherwise, you can remove it:

```
>>> dct = {"a":[1,2], "b":[3,4], "c":[5,6]}
>>> keys = ["a","b","c"]
>>> id(keys)
28561280
>>> keys = [dct[k] for k in keys]
>>> keys
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> id(keys)
28590032
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of ALL the values from a dict, use

```
>>> d={1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}  
>>> d.values()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

which returns a list of all contained values.

If you want a subset of the keys, you could use:

```
>>> d={1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}  
>>> l=[1, 3]
>>> [d[x] for x in l]  
['a', 'c']
```

Please let me know which you were going for...